# S3 copy command gives error + how to take away secret keys from copy command

Tags: python, amazon-s3, psycopg2, amazon-redshift, boto3

Why does my S3 copy command to redshift gives this error? This is the coppy command:

```
COPY dbtablename from 's3://rcname/foldername/file.csv CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=yyyyyyy/zzzz' CSV IGNOREHEADER 1;
```

My error is :

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "aws_access_key_id"
LINE 1: ...rcname/foldername/file.csv CREDENTIALS 'aws_access...
```

I have a second question : how do I remove the keys from my copy command. I'm using python and for the relation with S3 I used Boto3 and AWS CLI Keyring for encrypt my keys so I don't have to put the keys in my code

Now I want to do the same with the copy command (redshift). But I can't find a good alternative. Someone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the aws cli set up and have followed the steps in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html, then you will have two files in your home directory that already have the credentials:

```
~/.aws/config
```

and

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

You can use boto in python to access `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` from those files.

Specifically,

```
import boto
from boto import ec2
ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2', profile_name='default')

access_key = ec2.gs_access_key_id
secret_key = ec2.gs_secret_access_key
```

Now it is straightforward to insert those keys in your code:

```
query = '''
COPY dbtablename 
from 's3://rcname/foldername/file.csv' 
CREDENTIALS 
'aws_access_key_id={access_key};aws_secret_access_key={secret_key}'
CSV
IGNOREHEADER 1;
'''.format(access_key=access_key,secret_key=secret_key)
```

See https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs for examples of how to do this in other languages.

Comment: It works. But I still get the error "psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "aws_access_key_id"
LINE 1: ...rcname/foldername/file.csv CREDENTIALS 'aws_access..."

Comment: the error is the same, only now at line 5 because I previously wrote the query on 1 line:

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "aws_access_key_id"
LINE 5: 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxx;aws_secret_access_ke...
         ^

Comment: we were both missing a quote around the s3 path.  I edited it; try now.